# Java ME: How to display the output of a simple calculator?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I'm making a calculator using Java ME. I'm having a hard time displaying the output.

Here's my code:

```
  public void menuadd(){

  vswitch=2;
  Form formadd = new Form("addition");
  add1 = new TextField("1st Number:", "", 30, TextField.DECIMAL);

  add2 = new TextField("2nd Number:", "", 30, TextField.DECIMAL);
  disp = Display.getDisplay(this);
  cmdok = new Command("OK", Command.OK, 2);
  formadd.addCommand(cmdok);
  formadd.append(add1);
  formadd.append(add2);   
  formadd.setCommandListener(this);
  disp.setCurrent(formadd);
}
```

Comment: Instead of saying "I have a problem" try to get more specific help by pointing out what sort of problem you are facing and what is wrong with your output.

Comment: code snippet you posted here looks OK: should most likely display fine

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
public void commandAction(Command c,Displayable dy)
{
if(c.equals(cmdok))
{
int num1=Integer.parseInt(add1.getString());
int num2=Integer.parseInt(add2.getString());
int result=num1+num2;
formadd.append(result+""); // +"" required to convert Integer back to String
}
}
```

or describe please where do you want to put the result

Comment: Just a reminder... for this to work formadd must be an attribute and not a local variable at menuadd method.